# Changing state from "aspect: 4/3" to set variables "aspect: aspect_x/aspect_y" gives an error

Tags: reactjs, state

Trying to create two sliders which adjust the size of the crop window in an App I'm making. I'm trying to set the crop ratio to the set values "aspect_x" and "aspect_y" as seen below so I can change the values of them with a slider.

I get an error saying

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.
```

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      aspect_x: 4,
      aspect_y: 3,
      crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      zoom: 1,
      aspect: this.aspect_x / this.aspect_y,
      croppedAreaPixels: null,
      croppedImage: null,
      imageSrc: props.url,
      imageName: props.filename,
      cropSuccess: false
    };
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing here that your are calling function in your `render` incorrectly. can you show us how you setState please?

Comment: Have you implemented componentWillMount()